# What is wrong with the tag counter of Stackoverflow?

Tags: support, tags, question-count

Hi all,

I see that if I select all questions tagged "java" ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java))
the counter says that there are two or three questions less than in the menu at the right of the Stackoverflow Question page ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/)).

What could be wrong? Is it a problem with the database?

Thanks

Comment: I think this might belong on **META**. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Belongs in meta

Comment: Currently, it is the same. Strage...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The counts of the number of questions on a tag are denormalized, and updated periodically.

What you're seeing is just a time when a question has been retagged and the real count hasn't caught up yet.