# Wrong number associated with specific Tag

Tags: discussion, bug, tags

When I check the number of my tags, can see

[image: Bug count not correct]

I'm particularly interested in the bug count. It has 0 bug x5.

When I check [all my posts related with the tag bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:364217%20%5Bbug%5D),

[image: Bug count]

There's 6 results with a total of more than 20 upvotes. I know that [tags counts are](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/46652/364217)

> denormalized, and updated periodically

but one of the posts with upvotes is from 2019.

Can see that a similar problem is happening in other tags, like "review", and I've read about [tag calculation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79470/364217).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The score shown in the [tags tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=tags) in your profile is only the score obtained from the non-CW answers. (And you have [no answers in this tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A364217+%5Bbug%5D+is%3Aa).) The score in the tag is calculated in the same way for the purposes of the tag badges and in [the list of top answerers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/bug/topusers).

See also here: [Explain tag numbers in profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73164)

Actually, if you hover over the number next to the tag, you are shown a more detailed information.

[image: screenshot]

It might also be worth mentioning that the scores in the profile aren't updated immediately. (See: [Tag numbers in profile delayed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136990))

Comment: Oh right. Get the feeling this is not the first time I go through such mental process. There's no hover in mobile web though.